# Align multiple-line equation

Tags: align

I tried this code and it created a large space like this

```
\begin{align}
&C^\text {UL} &= \log_2\left|{\bf I}_M + \frac{\rho_\text{ul}}{K}{\bf H}{\bf H}^\dagger\right|\\
%\end{align}
%\begin{align}
&C^\text {DL} &= \log_2\left|{\bf I}_K + \frac{\rho_\text{dl}}{M}{\bf H}{\bf H}^\dagger\right| \nonumber \\
&&= \log_2\left|{\bf I}_M + \frac{\rho_\text{dl}}{M}{\bf H}{\bf H}^\dagger\right|  
\end{align}
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a full MWE.

Comment: Rather use `\mathbf{H}` than {`\bf H}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the `&` in front of the lines

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
C^\text {UL} &= \log_2\left|{\mathbf I}_M + \frac{\rho_\text{ul}}{K}{\mathbf H}{\mathbf H}^\dagger\right|\\
C^\text {DL} &= \log_2\left|{\mathbf I}_K + \frac{\rho_\text{dl}}{M}{\mathbf H}{\mathbf H}^\dagger\right| \nonumber \\
&= \log_2\left|{\mathbf I}_M + \frac{\rho_\text{dl}}{M}{\mathbf H}{\mathbf H}^\dagger\right|  
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works! Thank you very much

Comment: note `\bf` is not defined by default in LaTeX, use `\mathbf{I}`

Comment: Thank you, I will fix that. I'm a beginner :))

Comment: If you like my answer I'd be happy if you accept it :)

Comment: Please, fix `\bf`.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the hint. Adapted my answer.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to (a) removing the detrimental `&` symbols at the start of each line and (b) replacing `{\bf ...}` with `\mathbf{...}`, you may also want to (c) employ `\mathrm` instead of `\text` -- just in case this equation ever occurs inside a theorem-like environment -- and (d) reduce the heights of the absolute-value fences. For the final objective, I suggest you define an "absolute value" macro with the help of the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro of the `mathtools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert 
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
C^\mathrm{UL} &= \log_2\abs[\big]{\mathbf{I}_M 
                 + \frac{\rho_{\mathrm{ul}}}{K} \mathbf{H}\mathbf{H}^\dagger} \\
C^\mathrm{DL} &= \log_2\abs[\big]{\mathbf{I}_K 
                 + \frac{\rho_{\mathrm{dl}}}{M} \mathbf{H}\mathbf{H}^\dagger} \nonumber \\
              &= \log_2\abs[\big]{\mathbf{I}_M 
                 + \frac{\rho_{\mathrm{dl}}}{M} \mathbf{H}\mathbf{H}^\dagger}  
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That helps me a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `align`, use the `alignat` environment. The `alignat` environment will need an additional argument for the maximum number of left-right column-pairs you want to use, but giving a far larger number is not wrong.

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
    &C^\text {UL} &= \log_2\left|{\bf I}_M + \frac{\rho_\text{ul}}{K}{\bf H}{\bf H}^\dagger\right|\\
    &C^\text {DL} &= \log_2\left|{\bf I}_K + \frac{\rho_\text{dl}}{M}{\bf H}{\bf H}^\dagger\right| \nonumber \\
    &&= \log_2\left|{\bf I}_M + \frac{\rho_\text{dl}}{M}{\bf H}{\bf H}^\dagger\right|  
\end{alignat}
```

[image: rendered with alignat]
The difference to me is that `align` wants to make equal spacing between each column-pair, whereas `alignat` will move them as close together as the alignment will allow, then center the whole thing.

Be sure where you place the alignment markers as the left-right aligned nature of the columns will otherwise mess up your output.